# How to generate SQL COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY {ColumnName}) in LINQ-to-SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

Is it possible to generate the following SQL query by using LINQ-to-SQL query expression or method chains which is defer-executable?

**Data Structure**

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e062a48837.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e062a48837.jpg)

```
   Select Distinct ClassRoomTitle, 
                Count(*) Over(Partition By ClassRoomNo) As [No Sessions Per Room], 
                TeacherName, 
                Count(*) Over(Partition By ClassRoomNo, TeacherName) As [No Sessions Per Teacher] From ClassRoom
```

**Expected Result**

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/47a79fea8b.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/47a79fea8b.jpg)

Comment: cn you postan example of the resulting data?

Comment: I've just edited to include the expected result.

Comment: just edited my answer to fit your expected result

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        var vGroup = from p in ClassRoom
                     group p by new { p.ClassRoomNo, p.TeacherName }
                         into g
                         from i in g
                         select new
                         {
                             i.ClassRoomNo,
                             i.TeacherName,
                             i.ClassRoomTitle,
                             NoSessionsPerTeacher = g.Count()
                         };

        var pGroup = from p in vGroup
                     group p by new { p.ClassRoomNo }
                         into g
                         from i in g
                         select new
                         {
                             i.ClassRoomTitle,
                             NoSessionsPerRoom = g.Count(),
                             i.TeacherName,
                             i.NoSessionsPerTeacher
                         };

        var result = pGroup.OrderBy(p => p.ClassRoomNo).ThenBy(p => p.TeacherName);
```

I didn't test the above but you can check my original code in case I got something wrong in the rewrite:

```
        var vGroup = from p in Products
                     group p by new { p.ProductId, p.VariantId }
                         into g
                         from i in g
                         select new
                         {
                             i.ProductId,
                             i.VariantId,
                             VariantCount = g.Count()
                         };

        var pGroup = from p in vGroup
                     group p by new { p.ProductId }
                         into g
                         from i in g
                         select new
                         {
                             i.ProductId,
                             ProductCount = g.Count(),
                             i.VariantId,
                             i.VariantCount
                         };

        var result = pGroup.OrderBy(p => p.ProductId).ThenBy(p => p.VariantId);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var classRooms = from c in context.ClassRooms
                 group c by new {c.ClassRoomNo} into room
                 select new {
                    Title = room.First().ClassRoomTitle,
                    NoSessions = room.Count(),
                    Teachers = from cr in room
                               group cr by new {cr.TeacherName} into t
                               select new {
                                   Teacher = t.Key,
                                   NoSessions = t.Count()
                               }
                 };
```

A bit more structured than the posted expected result, but I find that to be better.

You can always use SelectMany if you want to go back to unstructured:

```
var unstructured = classRooms
   .SelectMany(c=> c.Teachers.Select( t=> new {
      Title = c.Title,
      SessionsPerRoom = c.NoSessions,
      Teacher = t.Teacher,
      SessionsPerTeacher = t.NoSessions
   });
```